# tRPC not fetching data correctly with nextjs pages router

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, trpc.io, trpc

I'm following the [TRPC documentation](https://trpc.io/docs/client/nextjs/server-side-helpers) to fetch data server side and avoid loading state while keeping refetching and what not.

Using Next JS with pages router.

I'm getting the data server side using `getServerSideProps`. The function `generateSSGHelper`is basically a copy of what is in the docs (I checked that I'm not generating context there using `req & res`, should not fail there)

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext<{ id: string }>) => {

  const helpers = generateSSGHelper()

  const id = ctx.params?.id

  if (typeof id !== 'string') throw new Error('no id')

  helpers.partner.getById.prefetch({ id })


  return {
    props: {
      trpcState: helpers.dehydrate(),
      id,
    }
  }
}
```

Just like in the docs, the dehydrated query is then used in the component:

```js
const SinglePartnerPage: NextPage<{ id : string }> = ({ id }) => {
 
  const partner = api.partner.getById.useQuery({ id }) // <= prefetched on server

  if (partner.status !== 'success') { // this condition should never be true
    console.log('Loading!!')
    return <>Loading...</>
  }

  return (
    ...
  )
```

It turns out that `Loading!` is printed in the console, so the query is indeed not success at some point, which is causing me problems in other parts of the component.

What am I doing wrong here? Is my approach not ok?